# Importing associated products and upsells using a Csv

Tags: magento, csv, import, dataflow

I am having a tough time finding a way to add associated products and upsells to my magento site.
I found a template from another webpage stating the .csv should look like this :

```
sku---links_upsell_sku---links_related_sku
```

I use the --- as a way to show the different cells.

I have tried using this, haven't met any errors in the dataflow import, but the products do not appear to have actually been added to the sku.

I'm just wondering if anyone has managed to nail the process I am discussing?

Comment: I also need to add that I need to achieve this without the use of plug-ins or extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the file should look like this (using your --- cell separation):

sku---name---price---links_upsell_sku---links_related_sku---etc..
--- --- --- links_upsell_sku
--- --- --- links_upsell_sku
--- --- --- --- links_related_sku
--- --- --- --- links_related_sku
sku---name---price---links_upsell_sku---links_related_sku---etc..
--- --- --- links_upsell_sku
--- --- --- links_upsell_sku
--- --- --- --- links_related_sku
--- --- --- --- links_related_sku

Comment: Note this format is for "Import/Export" files and not "Dataflow" files, which was the original question.